# Excel 2007 adding mean value and variance to histogram

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have to visualize a trend and I was wondering if it is possible to show a red line over a range of data for the mean value(data range) and the variance(data range).

Example:

Data:
a,b,c,d,...

Histogram:

```
         | 
|     |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
a  b  c  d ...
```

Histogram with trend lines for mean value and variance:

```
 --------|-- 
|-----|--|--|
|--|--|--|--|
a  b  c  d ...
```

Comment: I found the menu entry: Add Trendline. If I add a linear trendline and the line goes from the left lower corner to the right upper corner then the trend is increasing? What about the other trend lines: exponential, logarithmic, ... ?

Comment: A trendline attempts to show a pattern in your data. The different types simply apply different algorithms to fit your data to a linear, logarithmic, polynomial or exponential curve. If you want to show mean/median/variance, you'd need to calculate that separately and add it to the chart manually as a text box or another data series, depending on how you want to display it.

Comment: Ok. These are two separate things. I will use the trendline for forecast and make a separate display with lines for data, mean, var+ and var-. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

OP decided to "use the trendline for forecast and make a separate display with lines for data, mean, var+ and var-" because it was explained that a "trendline attempts to show a pattern in your data. The different types simply apply different algorithms to fit your data to a linear, logarithmic, polynomial or exponential curve. If you want to show mean/median/variance, you'd need to calculate that separately and add it to the chart manually as a text box or another data series, depending on how you want to display it."

In short, they had to add a new series.